# Angular i18n - Reverse extract translations to source code?

Tags: angular, internationalization, extract, translation, reverse

I've built an Angular application which obviously contains UI copy: labels for buttons, messages for errors, hints for form validation, etc. These texts are directly placed in the source code by me, a developer. Most of the time they are fine as is, but sometimes an editor wants to make changes. For instance, change “Next” into ”Proceed” or whatever. For this reason, and also to support other languages, I've added i18n to the project.

My setup is as follows:

- `dev`: The development language, my English
- `en`: The default language, editor’s English
- `nl-be`: An additional language, Flemish
- `fr`: An additional language, French

Whenever I add new UI copy to the source code, I extract it using the Angular command `ng extract-i18n --out-file messages.dev.xlf`. Using proprietary software, the editor can then override my English with his or hers and also provide translations for the other languages. The translation keys are saved to `messages.[language].xlf`. When the application is served on production, it uses `en` by default. Users can switch to `nl-be` or `fr` if they like.

Over time, the discrepancy between `dev` and `en` can build up however. This can create confusing situations where I, when developing, see different UI copy than the editor in the live environment. So this is where my question arises. **Is there a way to extract the translations from `messages.en.xlf` (the values inside the `<target>` tags) and apply them to the source code automatically?** I could do it manually, but with close to 100 changes over a multitude of files I was hoping to automate it.

Comment: you can't do that with the native i18n tool of angular, you can' change the language in runtime. you can to create different builds for each language. but it's possible if you use ngx-translae

Comment: Senne did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't. And since we're nearing the launch of the project, I will do it manually soon.